# Rowspan of html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have HTML table, how to do row span on specific columns using j-query. i want to row span on specific columns as can be seen in fiddle demo
here is  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bn9m1p6k/2/)

after HTML Result should be using jquery

Below is HTML.

```
<p>Before</p>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>131</td>
    <td>4155</td>
    <td>464</td>
    <td>46</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>After Sholud be using jquery (dynamically)</p>

<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>

    <td rowspan="2">1</td> <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>131</td>
    <td>4155</td>
    <td>464</td>
    <td>46</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i try this,but it does not work

```
groupTable($('#gvSearchRecord tr:has(td)'), 2,2);
                    $('#gvSearchRecord .deleted').remove();

function groupTable($rows, startIndex, total) {
        if (total === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var i, currentIndex = startIndex, count = 1, lst = [];
        var tds = $rows.find('td:eq(' + currentIndex + ')');
        var ctrl = $(tds[0]);
        lst.push($rows[0]);
        for (i = 1; i <= tds.length; i++) {
            if (ctrl.text() == $(tds[i]).text()) {
                count++;
                $(tds[i]).addClass('deleted');
                lst.push($rows[i]);
            }
            else {
                if (count > 1) {
                    ctrl.attr('rowspan', count);
                    groupTable($(lst), startIndex + 1, total - 1)
                }
                count = 1;
                lst = [];
                ctrl = $(tds[i]);
                lst.push($rows[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you render this table using JQuery ?

Comment: no i want row span using jquery,table already created using jquery but if same record found then there should be rowspan.this is my requirement,i try this logic,but it does not work.

Comment: what's your criteria for determining which table cell's should be span'ed ?

Comment: if same record in multiple rows found,records are sorted

Comment: i have given above fiddle demo for your reference

Comment: in your fiddle your number in element 0,0 is the same as the ones in the grouped rows 1,0 and 2,0.. why is that not grouped as well? (same for 2,1 2,2 2,3..) is youre example incorrect or is there something else happening here?

Comment: @ haxxxton this is just a static example,but i want to do something like this,group the rows.

Comment: i don't know  how many rows should be span,row should span on the basis of same record,

Comment: @dadyHawk will the number of columns always be equal for each row? ie. row 1..x have y columns?

Comment: @dadyHawk, if i understand what you're trying to do.. does this look like a correct example of after? http://jsfiddle.net/bn9m1p6k/4/

Comment: @ haxxxton  yes exactly i want to do this

Comment: row span would be decided on the basis of min same rows record count

Comment: if third row of same record then row span should be 3 . and so on

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bn9m1p6k/5/)**

The easiest way i found was to create a 2D array and then traverse it in reverse. This was the case, as `rowspan` works by pushing itself down, and if you remove a matching element from below, you then have trouble matching to the element above it when more than 2 are on top of one another.

There are assumptions that both your code and mine are making:

1. There is no header table row (can be fixed by changing the initial `processArray` element assignment selectors
2. No cells have `colspan` (if this is not the case, i will happily re-examine my code)

**JS**

```
var processArray = [];

// make things easier to traverse in reverse by first creating a 2D array of the table
$('#before tr').each(function(i){
    var processRow = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        processRow.push($(this));
    });
    processArray.push(processRow);
});

function computeDuplicates(){
    // we are starting at the last row and working up to row 2
    // we dont need to look at the first row, as we're looking at it from the row below
    for(var x = processArray.length - 1; x > 0 ; x--){
        for(var y = 0; y < processArray[x].length; y++){
            if(processArray[x][y].text() == processArray[x-1][y].text()){ //if the cell above has the same text as the current cell
                var currentRowSpan = processArray[x][y].attr('rowspan'); // get the current cell rowspan
                if(typeof currentRowSpan == "undefined"){ // no rowspan found on current cell
                    currentRowSpan = 2; // set default of 2
                }else{
                    currentRowSpan = parseInt(currentRowSpan, 10) + 1; // increase by 1
                }
                // apply currentRowSpan to above cell and delete current cell
                processArray[x-1][y].attr('rowspan', currentRowSpan);
                processArray[x][y].remove();
            }
        }
    }
    processArray = []; // remove from memory
}

computeDuplicates();
```

Comment: @dadyHawk can you explain how this is not a solution given it provides the **correct** output?

Comment: i want to row span only when rows have same values..in this example only row 2 and row 3 should be merge  and merging should be on basis of column no 1 , 3 and 4,,if these column's rows are same,then there will be merge,other wise not

Comment: @dadyHawk look at the original table.. in the 3rd column you have 3 '1's in a line.. in your result there is only '2' columns high.. you have put the 'rowspan' in your desired output in the wrong order in row 2..

Comment: but only second and third rows should be row span,because fourth row data change in column 1

Comment: so you ONLY want a limited number of rows to be processed? rows 2 and 3? (no where in your original question are you asking for this)

Comment: dear,i already explain "  
row span would be decided on the basis of min same rows record count"...

Comment: it will be really appreciated if  you help regarding this

Comment: @dadyHawk im afraid something is being lost in a potential language barrier here.. what do you mean by "min same rows record count".. that doesnt make sense

Comment: mean if there are three rows of same data then row span will be 3 and if five rows same data then row span  will be 5 and so on, mean there is no fixed row span value

Comment: thats exactly what my output creates.. your example titled "OUTPUT SHOULD BE:" in http://jsfiddle.net/bn9m1p6k/11/ .. the first table cell is a 1.. directly below it is a 1.. why is that not 3 rows high then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bn9m1p6k/12/ why is the yellow one in the second table.. not part of the red cells below it.. if you can tell me why you dont want them to be joined i can change my code.. but everything you've asked for so far sounds like you want them to be joined

Comment: so, ONLY if there are other `rowspan` elements in that row should they be `rowspan`ed.. ok.. that is doable.. but that's very different from what you originally asked for and showed in examples..

Comment: sorry if you misunderstand,but if any solution then please share

Comment: ok, so waht would happen if in column 4, row 1 there was a 1.. http://jsfiddle.net/opqbtezs/ option A.. or option B?

Comment: no,both wrong.row 1 should not span,because  row 1 -> column 3   does not 1

Comment: why does column 3 have more importance than column 4? is it because its closer to the left? is it that you need a minimum of 3 matching `rowspan` elements on each row? the rules for why you want this to happen dont seem to be consistent

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/opqbtezs/1/ output should be c. if you have any solution then argue.otherwise thanks for your co-operation

Comment: @dadyHawk, you're not explaining your rules for when columns should span rows correctly. you need to provide more examples with **different** data. If you come up with more examples i will gladly help.

Comment: i explain most of time when there is same rows then there should be row span.simple.!

Comment: @dadyHawk, that rule is followed in my original answer, you need to explain more clearly what you're after if the solution doesnt fit. I am here trying to help, please refrain from name calling

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your JSFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bn9m1p6k/6/

I've removed the list parameter and put the rowspan parameter in a data-attribute.
When the rowspan is directly applied, the table is changed and the following checks aren't correct.
Both the delete and rowspan are applied after all cells have been traversed.
This is the full code:

```
groupTable($('#gvSearchRecord tr:has(td)'), 0,5);
$('#gvSearchRecord .deleted').remove();
$('#gvSearchRecord td[data-rowspan]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('rowspan', $(this).attr('data-rowspan'));
});

function groupTable($rows, startIndex, total) {
    if (total === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var i, currentIndex = startIndex, count = 1, lst = [];
    var tds = $rows.find('td:eq(' + currentIndex + ')');
    var ctrl = $(tds[0]);
    for (i = 1; i < tds.length; i++) {
        if (ctrl.text() == $(tds[i]).text()) {
            count++;
            $(tds[i]).addClass('deleted');
        }
        else {
            if (count > 1) {
                ctrl.attr('data-rowspan', count);
            }
            count = 1;
            //lst = [];
            ctrl = $(tds[i]);
            //lst.push($rows[i]);
        }
    }
    groupTable($rows, startIndex + 1, total - 1);
}
```